# Run terminator in the necessary directory and then run necessary command

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminator

I want to open Terminator in a specific directory, for example `/home/downloads/`, and then run a command.

I did the first part by this "custom command": `cd /home/downloads; bash` 
Terminator now starts in this directory, but how I can do the second part?

Now that terminator was started in the downloads directory, I want to run any command I want, for example `ls` or `rake` command or use some aliases as commands. How can I do this?

I press right mouse button in terminator and choose Parameters, then Layouts, then i add text in Custom command section.

All these must be carried out automatically after the terminator start.

Comment: What command do you want to run? Just run it. Do you want this to happen automatically every time you open terminator? Please [edit] your question and i) clarify what you want to do and ii) tell us exactly how you set up this "custom command", was it in terminator's options?

Comment: Yes i want that first and then second command run automatically after i terminator run, but now i know only how to run first command and it's worked, but don't know how then run second command. First command is: "cd" to any catalog and second command must be any i want, in this catalog or not.
I edit my question. Sorry for my ugly language.

Comment: `teminator` and `remotinator` commands both document options for either `--execute` or `--command`.  I believe I understand the question fine, I want the bash command: `terminator new_tab --execute "cd /work/here; ls -l"` to open a terminal; execute that command string and **_remain_** open.  No custom command required.  I have set an option in the profile: "*When command exits*: **Hold the terminal open**" -- This doesn't seem to have any influence.  I'm seeking least *ONE* example where that command line that works with **v2.1.3**.

Answer (score 6):

Run `cd /home/downloads; exec bash` as the custom command. (The `exec` builtin ensures that `bash` will be a child of the terminal emulator; without it, it might end up being a grandchild.) You can run `terminator -e 'cd /home/downloads; exec bash'` on the command line.

You can't use aliases in the custom command because your aliases are defined by `~/.bashrc`, but that file is only loaded by interactive shells, not by the scripting shell that's used as a glue here between the terminal emulator and the scripting shell. If you want to use aliases, you need to load them explicitly. If you keep them in a separate file, that would be something like

```
. ~/.bash_aliases; cd /home/downloads; exec bash
```

or on the command line

```
terminator -x bash -c '. ~/.bash_aliases; cd /home/downloads; exec bash'
```

If your aliases are in `~/.bashrc`, then use `. ~/.bashrc`, but beware that there might be things in your `.bashrc` that cause errors because the shell isn't interactive. If this happens, the easiest solution is to split your aliases (and functions and any other setting that you want to use in the glue code) into a separate file and use `.` to include those from `.bashrc`.

Comment: Why can't `Asq` use `bash -i` to have the bashrc and aliases files loaded?

Comment: @will `bash -i` has more impact than just loading `.bashrc`. It's a possibility if you don't mind the other impact. I don't know the full list, see the bash manual or source code for that. I think it includes at least different signal handling, different handling of background processes (`-i` turns on job control), and some terminal initialization.

Comment: The use of `-i` is speified by the existing bash or terminator behaviour.  The `i` flag is set when a new tab is opened with `Ctrl+Shift-T` in terminator.  Basically do exactly what `Ctrl+Shift-T`  and execute the "necessary command(s)".  Thanks for the head-up.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for [activating virtual environments with Terminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524527/using-python-virtual-environments-with-terminator).

The trick is to do everything with just "one" command: `bash`. Taking advantage of its `-i` option (interactive) and using a custom `--rcfile` in which `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to whatever we want to execute. The result would be like this:

```
command = "bash --rcfile <(cat ${HOME}/.bashrc; echo 'export PROMPT_COMMAND="your commands; go here; unset PROMPT_COMMAND"') -i"
```

Simply replace `your commands; go here;` with your actual commands. [See this answer for an explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524527/using-python-virtual-environments-with-terminator).

Comment: Any idea why the command I specify can't be quit with ctrl+c?

Answer (score 2):

Just add the other command the same way you added the first one. For example, to run `ls`:

```
cd /home/downloads; ls; bash
```

You can add this to your profile's "command" option:

[image]

The reason that you don't get `rake` is that it is not in the default path. To use it, you need to specify the path. So, first run this command in your terminal:

```
type rake
```

That will return something like `/foo/bin/rake`. *That* is the path you need. Take it and add it to the Custom command above:

```
cd /home/downloads; /foo/bin/rake; bash
```

This won't work for aliases. Aliases are set up by your shell and won't be available here. A workaround is to use scripts instead. So, if you have an alias like this:

```
alias foo="command1 argument2"
```

Make a script, call it `foo.sh` and save it in `/home/youruser/bin`, with these contents:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
command1 argument2
```

And make it executable:

```
chmod a+x /home/username/bin/foo.sh
```

Then, in the "Custom command" section, use :

```
cd /home/downloads; /home/username/bin/foo.sh; bash
```

Comment: Yes i know this and "ls" command work, but 
1. for example "rake" command doesn't work and terminal show error: "/bin/bash: rake: command not found" 
2. I have some aliases, and for example "cd /home/downloads; 'aliasname'; bash" also doesn't work, terminal show the same error

Comment: @Asq well, yes, that's why I asked you to tell us _what command_ you want to run. Please edit your question and give specific examples. Aliases won't work, you can forget about that, but `rake` should if you use the full path `/path/to/rake`.

Comment: I must edit my main question? And what u mean " if you use the full path /path/to/rake"? I cd to the directory where i always use rake and it's work, but "cd /path/to/rake; rake; bash" doesn't work

Comment: @Asq yes, please edit your original question.  Don't do `cd /path/to/rake; rake; bash` do `/path/to/rake; rake; bash`.

Comment: :( i use rake command when i in /home/123 directory. I add now in custom command this: "/home/123; rake; bash" but console show me 2 errors:
1. /bin/bash: /home/123: This is a catalog
2. /bin/bash: rake: command not found

Comment: @Asq yes, I know you do but it won' be available in the Custom command because it's not in a directory in the default `$PATH` variable. See updated answer.

Comment: cool, thanks, i add "cd /home/downloads; /foo/bin/rake; bash" but how i can run for example "rake asd"?
Steps: 1. cd to some directory 2. From this directory run command "rake asd". All iss auto when term start.

Comment: @Asq just use `rake asd` instead of `rake`: `cd /home/downloads; /foo/bin/rake asd; bash` .

Comment: /foo/bin/rake asd doesn't work :(

Comment: @Asq as I have asked you before, please [edit] your question to add more information. Show us exactly what your current setup is (preferably with a screenshot like the one in my answer) and explain exactly how it fails. Any error messages?

Answer (score 2):

Just don't use '`command =`' to change directory. Use it for your actual command!

When editing `.config/terminator/config`, just specify

- '`directory = <dir>`' when you want terminal to automatically cd into one given dir, or
- '`command = <cmd>; <your_shell>`' when you want a custom command to execute, and not simply to change directory

For example:

- If you only want the terminal to cd into `<dir>` at startup, then specify 'directory' and leave 'command' empty:

  ```
  [[terminal7]]]
  directory = /home/dan/src/wmc
  order = 1
  parent = child3
  profile = default
  type = Terminal
  uuid = ebbe5595-06be-43ff-b7ce-4534aa6bb7f8
  ```
- If you only want to execute a custom command, only specify command:

  ```
  [[terminal7]]]
  command = /home/dan/mine/my-custom-command
  order = 1
  parent = child3
  profile = default
  type = Terminal
  uuid = ebbe5595-06be-43ff-b7ce-4534aa6bb7f8
  ```
- If you want both to cd into DIR and execute command:

  ```
  [[terminal7]]]
  directory = /home/dan/dl-dir
  command = /home/dan/mine/my-custom-command-to-run-in-dlDIR
  order = 1
  parent = child3
  profile = default
  type = Terminal
  uuid = ebbe5595-06be-43ff-b7ce-4534aa6bb7f8
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you right click on an open Terminator window, you can choose "Preferences." Chose the "Profile" and from there, the "Command" tab. There is a check box titled "Run a custom command instead of my shell."

I believe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working solution for this, using `bash`.  There will no doubt be suitable equivalent options for other shells.  Firstly, using `terminator` I would normally open a new terminal tab with **`Ctrl+Shift+T`**; a new tab opens:

```
$ #  examine bash start-up flags
$ printf %s\\n "$-"
himBEHTs
$
```

This is the current default shell in `terminator` for my Kubuntu 23.04 PC.  My goal is to have everything as it is currently launching with some preable commands.

To open a interactive new tab that remains open for my input from the command line or from within a script which ...

- Start in specified directory -- `$HOME/tmp/test`
- Executes a "*necessary command*" or commands.

You can follow the two examples below with a common '*test*' set-up; one for a new tab from the command line and then for a new window on the command line.

**Set-up**

Enter the following commands before each trial ...

```
$ ## start in 'current' tab
$ #    o Current directory: '~/tmp/new-tab'
$ #    o Target directory:  '~/tmp/test', or: '../test'
$ #    o Necessary command(s):
$ #        x touch abc;      # Create file "abc"
$ #    o Source the file in target directory: ./auto.bashrc, with
$ #      the following commands to demonstrate file was executed:
$ #        x echo "Working dir:" # Label for output
$ #        x pwd                 # Show current directory: ~/tmp/new-tab
$ #        x touch XXX           # Create file: XXX
$ #        x ls -l;              # List files ... check for 'abc' and 'XXX'
$ #        x echo "---- current location ----"
$
$ ##  Reset everything
$ #
$ cd ~/tmp/new-tab
$ rm ../test/abc  ../test/XXX
$ 
$ terminator --new-tab  --working-directory=$PWD/../test -x'touch abc; bash --rcfile ./auto.bashrc -i'
$
```

Where "`himBH`" is the required `bash option settings`.

**New Teminator Tab**

```
$ ##  New Terminator tab created, directory: ~/tmp/test
$ #
rm: cannot remove 'XXX': No such file or directory
Working dir:
/home/will/.tmp/test
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will   0 Oct  9 00:54 abc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will 133 Oct  9 00:52 auto.bashrc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will   0 Oct  9 00:54 XXX
---- current location ----
himBH
$
```

Where "`himBH`" is the required `bash option settings`.

Everything is optional.  I thought using `source` on a local file as a good example of ensuring that almost *any* command sequence is possible.

**New Teminator Window**

```
$ ##  Reset everything
$ #
$ cd ~/tmp/new-tab
$ rm ../test/abc  ../test/XXX
$ 
$ terminator --working-directory=$PWD/../test -x'touch abc; bash --rcfile ./auto.bashrc -i'
$
```

Terminator tab created:

```
rm: cannot remove 'XXX': No such file or directory
Working dir:
/home/will/.tmp/test
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will   0 Oct  9 00:54 abc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will 133 Oct  9 00:52 auto.bashrc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 will will   0 Oct  9 00:54 XXX
---- current location ----
himBH
$
```

In each case ... note the following:

- 'start' action is equivalent with: the `terminator`
- File `abc` was created (as example "necessary command");
- Existing: `auto.bashrc` file, is sourced in the new tab;

  - File: `XXX` created from: `./auto.bashrc`;
  - Working directory correctly output;
- Bash start-up flags match

Hopefully that's enough for others to come-up with a working pattern to suit their use case(s).