# Terminator cant run node commands

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminator

I'm making my custom terminator layout and filling custom commands for different tabs.

Ruby and rails commands works fine:[image]

but I don't know why my node commands does not start.

node, npm code looks something like this
[image]

after starting terminator, tab that runs 'npm start' shows this:
`-/bin/bash: npm: command not found`

if I run 'npm start' manualy it starts normally

also I think this has to do with access rights or something, because when i run terminator through console but not gui, all my custom commands starts and runs perfectlly including node commands

Answer (score 5):

I encountered a problem similar to the OPs issue (the OP tries unsuccessfully to run the `npm start` command in a Terminator Custom Command) when I attempted to run `jupyter notebook` in a Terminator Custom Command.

After some [additional googling](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233154/288238) I started to think that probably this had to do with my `~/.bashrc` not being loaded by Terminator on building the Layouts. I tried to `source ~/.bashrc` in my Terminator Custom Command (e.g. Custom command: `source ~/.bashrc; jupyter notebook`) but that *also* did not work.

Next, I [located my jupyter binary file](https://askubuntu.com/a/79066/588445) using `whereis jupyter`. I then used that absolute file path in my Terminator Custom Command, like `absolute/path/to/jupyter notebook`.

Success!